# Are they the same meaning?

Tags: meaning

> She is too beautiful for every boy to help gazing at.
>   She is so beautiful that every boy can't help gazing at her.

I'd like to know whether they are the same meaning.

Comment: The second sentence is fine. You need to add some details as to how you came up with the first one. It does not make sense to me.

Comment: First is ok although a little awkward. Perhaps *help but gaze at* is an improvement?

Comment: @user3169. I appreciate your comment, but I'd like to know more details why the first one is not acceptable.

Comment: *to help gazing at*, what does that mean?

Comment: "can/could (not) help (doing) sth" is an idiom. It means "can/could (not) prevent or avoid sth".

Answer (score 1):

Both seem to mean the same thing to me. However, I don't think you'd ever hear either of them spoken by a native speaker.

For future reference (though the rest of this doesn't answer your question):

In English, sometimes it is more common for us to reverse the negativity if it shortens the pronunciation. For example, it sounds better to a native speaker to hear this even though it only has one fewer syllables:

> She is so beautiful that no boy can help gazing at her.

But here is my alternative, which sounds much better than any of the others:

> She is so beautiful that boys can't help gazing at her.

Your second sentence has 16 syllables, while my alternative has 14. I think it sounds better because we tend to avoid using bigger words than we need to (in conversation). The first sentence has 15 syllables, but would absolutely never be spoken by a native because it ends with a preposition, which is uncomfortable. To a native, this makes the sentence *feel* like it is incomplete, and many institutions teach that it is incorrect outright.

We would also use "...so...that..." instead of "...too...for..." because in this instance, you are describing her beauty's effect on the boy's gazing. However, if you were describing its effect on her *being gazed at*, then we would use "...too...for..." (or "...too...to...")

For example, these sentences are correct:

> She is too beautiful to not be gazed at by boys.
>
> She is too beautiful for not being gazed at by boys.